# Javascript Object name that's calling function?

Tags: javascript, object, reference, parent

So I got this little piece of code, don't bother the way it's implemented.

```
function A() {}

A.prototype = {
    nw: function(t) {
        return new t(A);
    }
}
```

If a child (for example B) by prototype inheritance would call the function nw, and I want it to return new t(B), what do I have to replace A in new t(A) with to pass the right parameter?

Something like 'return new t(this)'?

B.nw(C) would return new C(B).

Comment: What do you want to pass in `t` function?
Instance of current object, parent object or root object?

Comment: you may try `this.prototype.constructor`, that is where we conventionally place the constructor method. Now assigning to prototype like that, I doubt it will work, you should use a design much like what coffescript generates.

Comment: Can you explain why `return new t(this)` doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh, the other answers just look complicated. It looks like you just want:

```
function A() {}

A.prototype = {
    constructor: A,

    nw: function(t) {
        return new t( this.constructor );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand this correctly, this is what you want:

```
function A() {}

A.__proto__ = {
    log: function(t) {
        return new t(this);
    }
}
```

If you run the following code

```
A.log(function(obj){
    console.log(obj);
});
```

It will log A

Comment: Yes, it is. See [ECMA-262, §4.2.1 Objects](http://es5.github.com/#x4.2.1): "*Each constructor is a function that has a property named “`prototype`” that is used to implement* prototype-based inheritance *and* shared properties." Notice that `__proto__` is never mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a simple inheritance mechanism:

```
var Class = function( parent ){
   var f = function(){};

   if( typeof parent == 'function' ){
      f.prototype = new parent;  
   }else if( parent) {
       f.prototype = parent;  
   }

   f.prototype.__parent = parent;  // :)
   f.prototype.__root = ( parent &&  parent.prototype && parent.prototype.__root) || parent || f; // :)
   return f
};
```

And now:

```
   var A = Class(),
       B = Class(A),
       C = Class(B),

       objA = new A,
       objB = new B,
       objC = new C;

objC.__parent == B; // true;
objB.__parent == A; // true

(objC.__root == objB.__root) && ( objA.__root == A ); // true;
```

However, you can specific prototype for root object( your case):

```
   var A = Class({ 
             nw: function( t ) {                  
                    // What you like here? :)    

                    return new t( this.__parent ); 
                    //return new t( this.constructor );  
                    //return new t( this.__root );
             } 
           });
```